# How to reset source control for messy project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I recently refactored an old project and altered its file/folder structure, which has caused big problems checking in. I can't check-in pending changes because parent folders have pending changes along with their children. I've tried checking in groups of changes at a time but to no avail.

Is there a way to reset the source control without erasing my TFS work items and change history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if everything is as you want it in TFS, you can delete Your local workspace, to clear any files you have locally.

You can then goto to Advanced>Source Control and choose specific Version.
[image: TFS Source Control Get Specific Version]

tick both boxes and click ok

[image: Overwrite Local Files]

when refactoring folder structures within TFS you are best to use the move function of TFS, (shown in first Pic). Move your folders, this way TFS will retain history, then open the solution and remap any projects that have moved